# Reading repeating tags using open xml or xml functions SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, openxml

```
<ActiveDig>
    <Dig IsPrim="True">
        <Code>3342</Code>
        <Name>abc</Name>
    </Dig>
    <Dig IsPrim="False">
        <Code>5342</Code>
        <Name>xyz</Name>
    </Dig>
</ActiveDig>
```

I'm trying to load it into table as follows:

```
| Dig_Isprim  |  Code  |  Name  |
|-------------|--------|--------|
|  True       |  3342  |   abc  |
|-------------|--------|--------|
|  False      |  5342  |   xyz  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**

```
Set @XML ='
<ActiveDig>
    <Dig IsPrim="True">
        <Code>3342</Code>
        <Name>abc</Name>
    </Dig>
    <Dig IsPrim="False">
        <Code>5342</Code>
        <Name>xyz</Name>
    </Dig>
</ActiveDig>
'

Select Dig_Isprim = lvl1.n.value('@IsPrim','varchar(50)') 
      ,Code       = lvl1.n.value('./Code[1]','varchar(50)') 
      ,Name       = lvl1.n.value('./Name[1]','varchar(50)') 
 From  @XML.nodes('ActiveDig/*')  lvl1(n)
```

**Returns**

```
Dig_Isprim  Code    Name
True        3342    abc
False       5342    xyz
```

> **EDIT -FULLY DYNAMIC SQL**

The following uses a Table-Valued Function to parse virtually any XML into a dataset.  Then we have some Dynamic XML within some Dynamic XML.

It may seem a little complicated, but when you look at the individual parts, it is not so bad.

**Example**

```
Declare @XML xml ='
<ActiveDig>
    <Dig IsPrim="True">
        <Code>3342</Code>
        <Name>abc</Name>
    </Dig>
    <Dig IsPrim="False">
        <Code>5342</Code>
        <Name>xyz</Name>
    </Dig>
</ActiveDig>
'


Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select * Into #Temp 
 From (
        Select *
              ,Item = concat(Element,IIF(Attribute='''','''',''_''),Attribute )
              ,RowN = sum(case when Lvl=2 then 1 else 0 end) over (Order by R1)
         From  [dbo].[tvf-XML-Hier](cast('''+cast(@XML as varchar(max))+''' as xml))  
      ) A
 Where Value is not null 

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = ''
Select *
 From ( Select RowN,Item,Value From  #Temp ) A
 Pivot (max([Value]) For [Item] in ('' + Stuff((Select Top 1000 '',''+QuoteName(Item) From (Select Distinct Item,Seq=min(R1) over (Partition By Item) from #Temp ) A Order By Seq For XML Path('''')),1,1,'''')  + '') ) p''
Exec(@SQL);

'
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Returns**

[image]

You may notice the only thing specified is Lvl 2... No attribute names or Node Names.

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-XML-Hier](@XML xml)

Returns Table 
As Return

with  cte0 as ( 
                  Select Lvl       = 1
                        ,ID        = Cast(1 as int) 
                        ,Pt        = Cast(NULL as int)
                        ,Element   = x.value('local-name(.)','varchar(150)')
                        ,Attribute = cast('' as varchar(150))
                        ,Value     = x.value('text()[1]','varchar(max)')
                        ,XPath     = cast(concat(x.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)'),'[' ,cast(Row_Number() Over(Order By (Select 1)) as int),']') as varchar(max))
                        ,Seq       = cast(1000000+Row_Number() over(Order By (Select 1)) as varchar(max))
                        ,AttData   = x.query('.') 
                        ,XMLData   = x.query('*') 
                  From   @XML.nodes('/*') a(x) 
                  Union  All
                  Select Lvl       = p.Lvl + 1 
                        ,ID        = Cast( (Lvl + 1) * 1024 + (Row_Number() Over(Order By (Select 1)) * 2) as int ) * 10
                        ,Pt        = p.ID
                        ,Element   = c.value('local-name(.)','varchar(150)')
                        ,Attribute = cast('' as varchar(150))
                        ,Value     = cast( c.value('text()[1]','varchar(max)') as varchar(max) ) 
                        ,XPath     = cast(concat(p.XPath,'/',c.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)'),'[',cast(Row_Number() Over(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)') Order By (Select 1)) as int),']') as varchar(max) )
                        ,Seq       = cast(concat(p.Seq,' ',10000000+Cast( (Lvl + 1) * 1024 + (Row_Number() Over(Order By (Select 1)) * 2) as int ) * 10) as varchar(max))
                        ,AttData   = c.query('.') 
                        ,XMLData   = c.query('*') 
                  From   cte0 p 
                  Cross  Apply p.XMLData.nodes('*') b(c) 
              )
    , cte1 as (   
                  Select R1 = Row_Number() over (Order By Seq),A.*
                  From  (
                          Select  Lvl,ID,Pt,Element,Attribute,Value,XPath,Seq From cte0
                          Union All
                          Select Lvl       = p.Lvl+1
                                ,ID        = p.ID + Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
                                ,Pt        = p.ID
                                ,Element   = p.Element
                                ,Attribute = x.value('local-name(.)','varchar(150)')
                                ,Value     = x.value('.','varchar(max)')
                                ,XPath     = p.XPath + '/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)')
                                ,Seq       = cast(concat(p.Seq,' ',10000000+p.ID + Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) ) as varchar(max))
                          From   cte0 p 
                          Cross  Apply AttData.nodes('/*/@*') a(x) 
                        ) A 
               )

Select A.R1
      ,R2  = IsNull((Select max(R1) From cte1 Where Seq Like A.Seq+'%'),A.R1)
      ,A.Lvl
      ,A.ID
      ,A.Pt
      ,A.Element
      ,A.Attribute
      ,A.XPath
      ,Title = Replicate('|---',Lvl-1)+Element+IIF(Attribute='','','@'+Attribute)
      ,A.Value
 From  cte1 A

/*
Source: http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10495/xquery-lab-58-select-from-xml.aspx

Declare @XML xml='<person><firstname preferred="Annie" nickname="BeBe">Annabelle</firstname><lastname>Smith</lastname></person>'
Select * from [dbo].[tvf-XML-Hier](@XML) Order by R1
*/
```

> **EDIT 2- Just to help with the Visualization**

If you were to simply run the following:

```
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-XML-Hier](@XML) Order By R1
```

**The Results would Be**

[image]

Comment: So this solution is with XML functions and not open xml right ?

Comment: @ivric Nope. Native XML parsing.  Never cared much for open xml.  But that is just me.

Comment: ok thanks alot. Also just curious to know if I could arrange the rows as columns ? like the following:                                                                                      Dig_Isprim  Code    Name  Dig_Isprim2  Code2    Name2

Comment: @ivric Not sure what you mean by rows as columns.  Are you looking to pivot?  Is there a defined number of columns... in this case 6 ?

Comment: Ya right I wanted to see all in one row even if the columns repeat, i'm trying insert them into one denormalized table.

Comment: @ivric Sure it can be done.  Still not clear if you need dynamic.  In the sample above, there are two rows, could there be more or less ?

Comment: Ya i have two rows for now, But I would appreciate if it can dynamically make columns for all the attributes & elements within every <Dig>  element.

Comment: @ivric Are you open to a UDF ?  This function will hash virtually any XML and return a dataset which then can be pivoted?

Comment: I read about UDF but i'm still not quite sure how to solve this with it, i think i need to look into it.

Comment: @ivric If I understand you correctly, the sample XML was just a simple example (which is fine), but you will have any number of nodes and attributes...  Give me a few minutes and I'll amend my answer with the UDF for your consideration.

Comment: Yes true I will have any number of nodes and attributes.

Comment: @ivric Take a peek at the EDIT

Comment: @ivric closing my office for the night.  I'll see comments or questions in the morning

Comment: @ivric One final note,  See Edit 2 ... Visualization

Comment: Wow this is really awesome, thank you so much I'm still looking into the dynamic sql example.

Comment: I'm trying to use your example code edit-2 and trying to get this: dig@IsPrim, Code, Name                                                                                   True             3342    abc                                                                                             False           5342    xyz

Comment: what I'm basically trying to get is: by still have it dynamically create new rows(records) for any new elements added "based on the lvl" if new element is added at lvl=1 or 2 it must be a new table, if new element is added at lvl=3 then that data must be added as a new record in the Dig table.

Comment: @ivric So you don't want code1,name1,code2,name2 but rather (using the sample xml) two records  code,name,+any other attributes/nodes ?

Comment: this  code1,name1,code2,name2 was good but didn't quite work especially when I'm trying to insert data into a table - as the table structure needs to be altered everytime which is not feasible. so yes, I'm working for a normalized solution which dynamically creates tables or add new rows to existing table based the lvl of that particular element/attribute.

Comment: @ivric See updated EDIT.  This will create a row for each DIG (level 2) with fields for all the attributes and/or nodes

Comment: @ivric failed to mention.   If you want to save the results into a new table or insert into an existing table.  Just modify the final select to Select * into YourNewTableName From (...